# django form is_valid always fails (extending django-registration form)

Tags: django, forms, signals, registration

I'm trying to extend Django registration to include my own registration form. In principle this is fairly simple. I just have to write my own form (`CustomRegistrationForm`) which is a child of the original one (`RegistrationForm`). Then I can process my specific input by using the user_registered signal of django registration.

So here is what I did:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from registration.views import register
from forms import CustomRegistrationForm
from django.contrib import admin
import regbackend
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', 'form_class': CustomRegistrationForm, 'template_name': 'custom_profile/registration_form.html'}, 
                        name='registration_register'),
)
```

**regbackend.py:**

```
from django import forms
from models import UserProfile
from forms import CustomRegistrationForm

def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = CustomRegistrationForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid(): # HERE: always fails
        user_profile = UserProfile()
        user_profile.user = user
        user_profile.matriculation_number = form.cleaned_data['matriculation_number']
        user_profile.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from models import UserProfile
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

attrs_dict = {'class': 'required'}

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    matriculation_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                                           label=_("Matriculation number"),
                                           max_length=12,
                                           error_messages={'invalid': _("This value has to be unique and may contain only numbers.")},
                                           initial=108)

    def clean_matriculation_number(self):
        print "Validating matriculation number."
        data = self.cleaned_data['matriculation_number']
        if len(data) != 12:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Matriculation number consists of exactly 12 digits."))
        return data
```

So the problem is the `is_valid()` function, because it always returns `False`. Even if there are no errors! So what is wrong? I spent hours on this  one and I have no idea anymore :(

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Why is the form expecting `files=request.FILES`?

Comment: `is_valid` will only return `False` if there is any error. Maybe there is an error for a field you are not displaying. Or not displaying the errors at all. Use `django-debug-toolbar` for checking for form errors (or do the deep inspection yourself).

Comment: @ Abid: I added files=request.FILES to avoid an unbound form or something. At first I used only the line form = CustomRegistrationForm(request.POST) and it wasn't working.
@ bouke: I'm using the toolbar and I explicitly checked for errors. There are none.

Interestingly eerythin works if I skip the is_valid() function and use form.data[...] instead of cleaned_data. So there is definately a problem with the validation :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I solved it (more or less).

I'm still not really sure, why the form did not validate. But as I said I was extending django-registration and the 'register' view already called is_valid() of the form, so I can assume that the form is valid when I process the posted data any futher. The view then calls the backend

```
backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
```

with the request and the cleaned data (which is just username, email and password). So I can't use it for registration because my additional information is missing. The backend then fires the signal that I am using and what I did is, is that I created the form again with the provided request. This form, however, will NOT validate (and I tried everything!!) I looked it up, I am doing the exact same thing as django-registration, but it's not working in my code.

So I did not really solve the problem, because the form is still not validating. But I found peace with this, when I realized that the form was already validated by the 'register' view. So I am using form.data[..] instead of form.cleaned_data[..] now which shouldn't be a problem...

Answer (score 2):

The reason `form.is_valid()` fails is probably because the form's "clean_username" function checks if the username passed to it already exists. Since the signal is sent after the User object is created and added to the database, the form will fail to pass this test every time. My guess would be if you logged `form.cleaned_data` after `is_valid()` returns `False`, you'll get a list of all of the fields except the username.

`form.data` might not contain changed values for the fields if the form clean_ function makes any changes (I couldn't find much documentation on form.data).

To avoid the potential problems this might cause, I made two classes for my custom registration form:

```
# I use this one for validating in my create_user_profile function
class MyRegistrationFormInternal(forms.Form):
    # Just an example with only one field that holds a name
    name = forms.CharField(initial="Your name", max_length=100)    
    def clean_name(self):
        # (Optional) Change the name in some way, but do not check to see if it already exists
        return self.cleaned_data['name'] + ' foo '
# This one is actually displayed
class MyRegistrationForm (MyRegistrationFormInternal):
    # Here is where we check if the user already exists
    def clean_name(self):
        modified_name = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).clean_name()
        # Check if a user with this name already exists
        duplicate = (User.objects.filter(name=modified_name)
        if duplicate.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("A user with that name already exists.")  
        else:
            return modified_name
```

Then, instead of using the form.data (which may still be "unclean" in some ways), you can run your POST data through `MyRegistrationFormInternal`, and `is_valid()` shouldn't always return false.

I realize this isn't the cleanest solution, but it avoids having to use the (possibly raw) form.data.